# CSS table styling only working with specific cell, but overwriting other

Tags: css, html-table, css-selectors

I'm trying to style a table. I want the first element of the last row to have background-color blue, and the last one, background-color red. But somehow, I only get the last one red, why?

Here is the CSS code

```css
table tr {
  text-align: center;
}

table th:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}

table td:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}​ 

tr:last-child>td:first-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}

tr:last-child>td:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Hello</th>
    <th>Hello1</th>
    <th>Hello2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>G</td>
    <td>H</td>
    <td>I</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>J</td>
    <td>K</td>
    <td>L</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>aaaaa</td>
    <td>bbbb</td>
    <td>cccc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you!!! =)

Comment: You could use    tr:last-child > td:nth-child(1) {    background-color: blue; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow this one took me a sec.
Your code should absolutely work and after I copied your code into the editor I found a character that wasn't visible but screwed up the next declaration you made which happened to be the one you had trouble with:

[image]

*Note the red dot on line 11*

Removing that will make your code work without changes.

```css
table tr {
    text-align: center;
}

table th:first-child{
    text-align: left;
}

table td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}

tr:last-child>td:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;  
    background-color: blue;
}

tr:last-child>td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
    background-color: red;  
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><th>Hello</th>
        <th>Hello1</th>
        <th>Hello2</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>G</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>I</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>J</td>
        <td>K</td>
        <td>L</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>aaaaa</td>
        <td>bbbb</td>
        <td>cccc</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow, that's weird... I've checked on Microsoft Visual Code and there is no invisible character. However, in the stackoverflow editor I could spot it, and indeed, after I've deleted, the code worked. What can I do to fix this on visual studio? hahaha I even tried to not let any space in between sections, but still didn't work on visual studio =(
Any Idea what to do? thank you!

Comment: No idea about your IDA @digolira2. I use a different editor. Glad this solved it for you. Feel free to mark this as the answer ;)

Comment: @AHaworth When you click on the `Run code snippet` button you can see my suggested code works and shows the first item in the last row with blue background. Not sure what you're on about but I'm sure the question was phrased a bit unfortunate.

Comment: I understand what  @AHaworth  was saying, in fact, it was my bad, I had written "column" instead of "row", already edited haha thank you.

Comment: Apologies, I read the question the wrong way round. The code works.

Comment: Ah, that makes me feel better, thanks for clarifying, I guess I was trying it out just as you were editing it. Glad it's all solved.

Comment: No worries at all @AHaworth. I know the frustrations when you're trying to help and someone else get's there first. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is one apparently unintended character in your CSS code, right after the closing bracket of the third CSS rule. If your erase that, your code works as expected.

```css
table tr {
    text-align: center;
}

table th:first-child{
    text-align: left;
}

table td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}

tr:last-child>td:first-child{
    border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;  
    background-color: blue;
}

tr:last-child>td:last-child{
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
    background-color: red;  
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><th>Hello</th>
        <th>Hello1</th>
        <th>Hello2</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>G</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>I</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>J</td>
        <td>K</td>
        <td>L</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>aaaaa</td>
        <td>bbbb</td>
        <td>cccc</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```